# Polymer 1.0 dom-if does not recalculate when previously true

Tags: media-queries, polymer

I have the following component that displays a specific image based on a media query. What I'm expecting to see is when the window is resized, that a different image will be loaded and displayed, and  all other sizes "hidden".

What I'm getting though, is that the new image is indeed loading, but old images are not hidden. They remain visible. If I refresh the page, then the correct image is displayed. is it the iron-media-query that is not updating it's property correctly, or is it the template[dom-if] tags that isn't updating accordingly.

```
<dom-module id="app-image">
    <!-- Should select correct image based on size -->
    <style>
        :host {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        :host > ::content img { display: block; }
    </style>
    <template>
        <iron-media-query query="(max-width: 421px)"
                        query-matches="{{isTiny}}"></iron-media-query>
        <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 422px) and (max-width: 641px)"
                        query-matches="{{isSmall}}"></iron-media-query>
        <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 642px) and (max-width: 1201px)"
                        query-matches="{{isMedium}}"></iron-media-query>
        <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 1202px)"
                        query-matches="{{isLarge}}"></iron-media-query>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isTiny}}">
            <content select="[tiny]"></content>
        </template>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isSmall}}">
            <content select="[small]"></content>
        </template>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isMedium}}">
            <content select="[medium]"></content>
        </template>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isLarge}}">
            <content select="[large]"></content>
        </template>

    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "app-image"
    });
</script>
```

And here is some sample code of this tag in use:

```
<app-image>
    <img tiny src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/abstract/" />
    <img small src="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/food/" />
    <img medium src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/animals/" />
    <img large src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/city/" />
</app-image>
```

Comment: I don't really think using `dom-if`s is the right route here. Try wrapping these contents in a `div` instead and applying `hidden$="{{logic}}"` there.

Comment: While this approach works, it bypasses the fundamental reason for using <template>. The content is not added to DOM untill template is "stamped"; which also means the images are not requested until template is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this was answered in a github issue I logged, and turns out there is indeed a way to tell the template it needs to "re-stamp" itself.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{active}}" restamp="true">
    <content></content>
</template>
```

It's actually very clearly documented [1]; I guess I was reading over the docs too fast just looking for the code snippets, rather than properly understanding the element.

[1] https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-if

Comment: `restamp` is a Boolean attribute, thus just setting `restamp` will work instead of `restamp="true"`

Answer (score 1):

I just combined my suggestion with yours. It sort of solves your problem.

```
<dom-module id="app-image">
    <!-- Should select correct image based on size -->
    <style>
        :host {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        div > ::content img { display: block; }
    </style>
    <template>
        <iron-media-query query="(max-width: 421px)"
                        query-matches="{{isTiny}}"></iron-media-query>
        <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 422px) and (max-width: 641px)"
                        query-matches="{{isSmall}}"></iron-media-query>
        <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 642px) and (max-width: 1201px)"
                        query-matches="{{isMedium}}"></iron-media-query>
        <iron-media-query query="(min-width: 1202px)"
                        query-matches="{{isLarge}}"></iron-media-query>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isTiny}}">
            <div hidden$="{{!isTiny}}">
                <content select="[tiny]"></content>
            </div>
        </template>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isSmall}}">
            <div hidden$="{{!isSmall}}">
                <content select="[small]"></content>
            </div>
        </template>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isMedium}}">
            <div hidden$="{{!isMedium}}">
                <content select="[medium]"></content>
            </div>
        </template>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isLarge}}">
            <div hidden$="{{!isLarge}}">
                <content select="[large]"></content>
            </div>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "app-image"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes this does solve the problem as a temporary workaround. Images are only requested, when size is loaded initially, and even though the template is not hidden, the hidden$="" divs takes care of that.

Comment: My apologies, I spoke too soon. For some reason all 4 images are still loaded. I'm guessing it's got something to do with the new API and how light dom is treated with <content>. This approach worked well in 0.5 though.

Comment: This may mean that `dom-if` is not exactly inert as a template element should be.

Comment: I'll go log a issue on github for this then

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define these 4 properties in Polymer:

```
Polymer ({
 is: "app-image",
 properties: {
  isTiny: Boolean,
  isSmall: Boolean,
  isMedium: Boolean,
  isLarge: Boolean,
 }
});
```